# django display message issue after POST form submit?

Tags: django

Whenever I am using messages function, I get an error

```
File "D:\Django Project\ta2\practice\views.py", line 60, in changepassword
    messages.SUCCESS(request,'your password has been updated')
TypeError: 'int' object is not callable
```

Here is my views.py

```
def register(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        fm = new_registration_form(request.POST)
        if fm.is_valid():
            fm.save()
            messages.add_message(request, messages.SUCCESS, 'Thanks for the registration')
    else:       
        fm = new_registration_form()     
    return render(request,'register.html',{'form':fm})
```

Here is my register.html part containing messages information

```
div class="alert-info">{% if messages %}
        {% for message in messages %}
        {{message}}
        {% endfor %}
        {% endif %}</div>
```

Comment: are you sure you posting the right view? there no `messages.SUCCESS(request,'your password has been updated')` in the view you posted

Answer (score 0):

`messages.success(request, 'Profile details updated.')` replace it with `messages.add_message(request, messages.SUCCESS, 'Thanks for the registration')`

Comment: It worked. but why messages.success(request, 'Profile details updated.') did not work. I have seen people using it and it works too.

Comment: it didn't work because messages.SUCCESS returns  a value which is an Integer to represent the message Level, while messages.success(request, "message body") or message.add_message(request, messages.SUCCESS, 'message body') creates a message for the next view

Comment: in short...the is a big difference between messages.SUCCESS and messages.success